# Хочу чтобы открывалось модальное окно (popup) вместо новой вкладки

Tags: javascript, popup, окно, ссылка

При нажатий на ссылку открывается новое окно, но хочется, чтобы было всплывающее окно. Знаю, что ошибка в `Window.open` или `Window.New` и т.д. Просто не знаю, как можно сделать это.

```
href="ссылка" target="_blank" onclick="if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera') != -1 &amp;&amp; window.event.preventDefault) window.event.preventDefault();this.window = window.open('ссылка'+escape(document.location.href)+'&amp;referrer='+escape(document.referrer), 'webim', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,width=640,height=480,resizable=1');this.newWindow.focus();this.newWindow.opener=window;return false;"> </a><!-- / webim button --></p>
```

Comment: iq 999 писать javascript в html коде кнопки, конечно

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.open("about:blank", "hello", "width=200,height=200");
```

Из [отсюдаво](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods)